# Как нескольким определенным классам правильно добавить один общий класс через JS

Tags: javascript, html, классы

Я знаю, как сделать присвоение классов определенному классу, но как можно было бы грамотно написать присвоение различным классам - одного общего? Я не программист, но понимаю что вариант дублирования - это плохо.

Вариант 1:

```
$('css-class-1').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-2').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-3').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-4').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-5').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-6').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-7').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-8').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-9').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-10').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-11').addClass('css-general-1');
$('css-class-12').addClass('css-general-1');
```

Копаясь в вопросах, кажется, нашел более правильное решение.

Вариант 2:

```
for (var element of document.querySelectorAll(".css-class-1, .css-class-2, ... .css-class-12")) {
  element.classList.add("css-general-1");}
```

Но правильно ли так в одну длинную строку писать много css классов?
Есть варианты, как было бы грамотнее, на чистом JS?

Comment: Если вы используете jquery (судя из первого кода), вы вроде можете так же выбрать несколько элементов через запятую.

Comment: То есть, вы имеете ввиду такую запись?

`$('css-class-1, css-class-2, css-class-3 ...').addClass('css-general-1');`

считается ли такая строка грамотной с точки зрения программирования, если например классов много и строка очень длинная?

Comment: Ну наличие такого кол-ва классов однотипных.. мне кажется у вас явно что-то не так с архитектуртой.

Comment: Скажите, Dvalord, зачем вы используете классы по-кривому? Вы знаете назначения классов? И отличия их от идентификаторов? Если нет - прочитайте. Тогда решение очень быстро придёт само

Comment: Я делаю сайт в конструкторе Tilda, и некоторый функционал невозможно реализовать без обращения к коду (я только учусь). В конструкторе есть возможность присваивать только один класс к созданному элементу, и к нему обращаться. Имеется меню с 13-ю кнопами, ведущих на разные страницы, и к каждой кнопке присвоен класс. На каждой отдельной странице вставлен код, меняющий border-color активной страницы по классу (вычитал этот вариант на старых форумах). Добавление класса к такой архитектуре мне необходимо чтобы придавать всем кнопкам единый hover эффект на border в половину яркости от активного.

Answer (score 0):

Решения вопроса с использованием JQuery и чистого JS:

```js
// На JQuery
$('#add-class').click(() => {
    $('.container').children().addClass('active')
})
$('#remove-class').click(() => {
    $('.container').children().removeClass('active')
})

// На чистом JS
const parentElement = document.querySelector('.container')
const childrenElements = Array.from(parentElement.children)
const addClassBtn = document.getElementById('add-class')
const removeClassBtn = document.getElementById('remove-class')
addClassBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    childrenElements.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.add('active')
    });
})
removeClassBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    childrenElements.forEach(element => {
        element.classList.remove('active')
    });
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="weqwe">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="dasdasd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="fdvdfa">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="wcdgshfsaf">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="kjdhvpashdpdsa">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="dkjhaksjdhvicuhap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
      <div class="lsjfpiusfoiduspfsd">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <button id="add-class">Добавить класс</button>
  <button id="remove-class">Удалить класс</button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Всё-такие вам надо было прочитать разницу между классами и идентификаторами .... Почитайте, не ленитесь.....................в итоге, если бы почитали, то вы бы нужным дивам поставили бы всем класс `test` (или другой любой) и код был бы: `$('.test').addClass('active')`  вот на столько просто

Comment: ок, а если эти дивы генерируются JS-ом то как вы им зададите класс? Обходить их циклом чтобы добавить класс и по этому классу добавлять новый?? К тому же если в дальнейшем будут добавляться новые дивы - код будет работать, независимо от того есть там класс 'test' или нет(в отличие от вашего). И да ваш код короче, аж на целый метод...браво)))

Comment: Ну чего вы кипятитесь? Один метод, порой, спасает тонны памяти. А бездумно клепать цепочки - это не есть хорошо........... Если брать генерацию дивов **с рандомными классами** - окей.. подход более правильный. Только задайте теперь вопрос себе: что будет, если  в контейнере дети будут не только div, но и , предположим, заголовой (h1-h5) или другая вспомогательная информация или секция? И если вы смогли задать класс для одного дива, то почему, при генерации JS - не добавить детям один класс? Какая-то дичь))

Comment: Цель была получать дивы с разными классами из общего родителя, цель достигнута. Если там будут какие-то еще элементы - то да, ваш метод будет единственным рабочим.

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать css селектор по атрибуту `class`.

```
for (var element of document.querySelectorAll("[class^=css-class-]")) {element.classList.add("css-general-1");}
```

В этом коде querySelector выберет все теги с классом начинающимся с `css-class-`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

```js
function addClass() {
  for (var element of document.querySelectorAll("[class^=css-class-]")) {
    element.classList.add("css-general-1");
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.css-general-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-class-1"></div>
<div class="css-class-2"></div>
<div class="css-class-3"></div>
<div class="css-class-4"></div>
<div class="css-class-5"></div>
<div class="css-class-6"></div>
<div class="css-class-7"></div>
<div class="css-class-8"></div>
<div class="css-class-9"></div>
<div class="css-class-10"></div>
<div class="css-class-11"></div>
<div class="css-class-12"></div>
<br>
<button class="button" onClick="addClass()">Добавить класс</button>
```

Comment: Вы в селекторе `^` забыли

Comment: Мне кажется если класс будет стоять не в начале - не сработает.

Comment: @EzioMercer, да, спасибо.

Comment: @OliverPatterson, поэтому я привел ссылку на MDN, там есть разные способы выбора.

Comment: Приблизительно, что-то подобное мне и нужно было, но почему-то это не работает.

Comment: @Dvalord я не знаю что вы делаете, смотрите в консоль, в devtools, почему у вас не работает. На всякий случай добавил модельный код - здесь все работает.